# How might I go about making the .sort() method sort by more than just the first digit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I am trying to sort a list. But when I try, it always seems to sort by just the first digit.

This is my code:

```
data = input("enter your data separated by spaces: ")
data = data.split(' ')
data.sort()
```

My input is just numbers. eg. 1 25 3 466 4 32 5
but with this input the output is something like 1 25 3 32 466 4 5
my goal is to have the variable data sorted properly. I would like the output for the input mentioned earlier to be 1 3 4 5 25 32 466. I am new to python so i apologize if this question is simple or if my terminology is off.

Comment: please provide an example of the input list and the output list

Comment: In general: write a `key` method. But we can't help more than that because we've no idea what data you're trying to sort, how you're trying to sort it or what you've already tried. Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html. At a guess you're surprised by lexicographical sorting of strings representing numbers, in which case maybe try converting them to actual numbers before sorting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sorting the input alphabetically:

```
>>> sorted(["5", "10", "1", "100"])
['1', '10', '100', '5']
```

`'5' > '100'`, in the same way that `'e' > 'a'`, or `'east' > 'apple'`, they come later in [ordinal values](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#ord):

```
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> ord('e')
101
>>> ord('1')
49
>>> ord('5')
53
```

Since you're sorting numbers, convert your input to numbers before sorting them:

```
>>> data = input("enter your data separated by spaces: ")
enter your data separated by spaces: 1 10 100 5
>>> data = [int(n) for n in data.split(' ')]
>>> data.sort()
>>> data
[1, 5, 10, 100]
```

If you want to keep them strings, you can use use a key to compare the input as integers:

```
>>> data = input("enter your data separated by spaces: ")
enter your data separated by spaces: 1 10 100 5
>>> data = data.split(' ')
>>> data.sort(key=int)
>>> data
['1', '5', '10', '100']
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a list of numbers, you have a list of *strings* that happen to be (hopefully) string representations of numbers. So, they get sorted as strings. As a string, `"25"` comes before `"3"`, for the same reason that `"Jacky"` comes before `"K"`.

There are two basic ways to fix this.

If you actually want a list of numbers, convert each string to a number. For example:

```
data = [int(numstr) for numstr in data]
```

If you want to keep a list of strings, but still *sort* them as if they were numbers, you can use a `key` function:

```
data.sort(key=int)
```

Either of these will raise a `ValueError` is someone types `spam` instead of `25`. You need to decide what you want to do in that case. Maybe just failing with a `ValueError` is fine. Or maybe you want a loop, asking for a new input line forever until they give you a valid one. Or maybe you want to silently skip over non-integers, or sort them to the end, or… whatever you want to do, you can do it, but not until you decide what you want.